# R function definition in Visual Studio v.s. R Gui

Tags: r, visual-studio, rtvs

When I write function name without parenthesis in R Gui (e.g. `library`) I see the complete function definition (several pages of code); in Visual Studio 2017 environment I see only the following:

```
function (...) 
{
    if (nargs() == 0) {
    invisible(rtvs:::send_notification("!Library"))
}
else {
    base::library(...)
    }
}
<environment: namespace:rtvs>
```

Why Visual Studio shows abbreviated version? Are they equivalent? How can I get the complete function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's investigate the code you copied in.

```
if (nargs() == 0) {
invisible(rtvs:::send_notification("!Library"))
}
```

`rtvs` is a Visual Studio R library.  The code defaults to `rtvs` library-related functionality unless there are arguments and then the `base::library()` function is called.  In this case, the function code shown is not abbreviated (`...` is representing any arguments that are passed to `library()`).

You can also tell the function is not base R code from the `<environment: namespace:rtvs>` environment details at the bottom.

For viewing function defintions of all function types in R, [How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) has some nice answers.